# In firefox caret in a contenteditable div appearing left always

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a content-editable div, and for that div I am using css property

```
#DIVID {
    text-align: right;
}
```

when I start typing text appears right align, but on clicking on the div (without any text) caret appears at the left end.
This issue is occurring only in Firefox.

Comment: text-align:right; aligns right. can you post the little more code here so we can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox you might need to include this line in your CSS file.

```
text-align: end;
```